# jQuery radio button value when it is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have 10 radio button/buttonset from jQuery. Of course every button has its own value, and I want to show the value beside the button, when the button is hovered.

How can I deal with it?

Illustration:

> row1 : radio1.1 radio1.2 radio1.3 **print value radio in here when
> radio is hovered**
>
> row2 : radio2.1 radio2.2 radio2.3 **print value radio in here when
> radio is hovered**
>
> row3 : radio3.1 radio3.2 radio3.3 **print value radio in here when
> radio is hovered**

I have used `live function` from jQuery to get event `mouseover`, but how can I specific place the value into specific row?

How can I get which radio is hovered, so I can get its value?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="jslib/jquery_theme/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script src="jslib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jslib/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
      
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ter").buttonset();
      });
      
      
      
      $('.ter > label').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
      if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
        document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "Hello World";
      //this is when radio is hovered, it should show radio value beside the rwadio
      } else {
         document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "out";
         //this is when mouse is out from radio
      }
});
  
$(function() {
    $("#radio :radio").change(function(e) {
       alert(
           "run ok"
       );
    });
});



  </script>


</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
  
<div id="radio">
    <form name='tes' method='post' action='a.php'>
    <?php for($I=0;$I<10;$I++){ 
        
        echo"
        <div class='ter' style='border:1px solid; width:400px; margin-bottom:5px;'>
      
    <input type='radio' id='radio1.$I' name='radio.$I' value='4' /><label for='radio1.$I'>  </label>
    <input type='radio' id='radio2.$I' name='radio.$I' checked='checked' value='3' /><label for='radio2.$I'> </label>
    <input type='radio' id='radio3.$I' name='radio.$I' value='2' /><label for='radio3.$I'> </label>
        <input type='radio' id='radio4.$I' name='radio.$I' value='1'/><label for='radio4.$I'> </label>
        <span id='mydiv'>aaaaaaaaaa</span> 
        </div>  ";
         } ?>
        <div class='ter'>
        <input type='submit' value ='submit'>
        </div>
    </form> 
            
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget to apply the effect on 'focus', as well as 'hover', to enable it to work with keyboard navigation, and touch devices such as iPads/phones.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ter > label').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = $("#"+$(this).attr("for")).val();
  //this is when radio is hovered, it should show radio value beside the rwadio
  } else {
     document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "";
     //this is when mouse is out from radio
  }
```

This will put the radio value corresponding to the label, and now you can position the div accordingly.

Comment: I owuld recommend you switch to 'on' instead of `live`

Comment: thanks for your respond.....but when i hovered, the second row of radio button, it show value in first row, how can I manipulate span element in order to show the value in second row?

Answer (score 0):

as i understand from your words, the event will be at the radio buttons

```
$('input[type=radio]').live({
   mouseover:function(){
      var value = $(this).attr('value');
      $(this).next().html(value);
   },
   mouseout:function(){
      $(this).next().html("");
   }
});
```

when the radio button is hovered, then get it's value and print it in the label(next).

Comment: yes..but radio is placed by span, label in jquery ui buttonset

Comment: if i hover radio1.1, next element will be radio1.2 not the span...and it won't showed the value into span

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect without javascript, using only HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```
​<form>
   <label><input type="radio" name="Test" value="Something"/></label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="Test" value="Something else"/></label>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
input:hover:after,
input:focus:after {
    content: attr(value);
    padding-left: 2em;
}​
```

This takes advantage of the CSS `content` property to extract and display the values of elements it's applied to. You might need to work with the CSS to style it how you want - I'm thinking absolute positioning, relative to each row.

This won't work in older versions of IE. 8+ will definitely work - I'm not sure about 7 and below.